# Adding minutes to time in mysql database and comparing it with Time.now

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can we add some minutes to time from the mysql database and compare it with Time.now?

Here is the working code,

```
user.update_all(last_failed_attempt_time: Time.now.to_s) #setting the time
# some logic

time = user[0].last_failed_attempt_time #from the User model

time.to_i < Time.now.to_i #This works correctly
```

Above comparison is done correctly, but if I add 10 minutes to the time coming from the database, the condition checking does not work as it should,

```
user.update_all(last_failed_attempt_time: Time.now.to_s) #setting the time
# some logic

time = user[0].last_failed_attempt_time + 10.minutes #adding 10 minutes

time.to_i < Time.now.to_i # This should not let the control flow through it, but it is
```

Am I comparing different objects? Rails does not give me any error.

Comment: what is the issue, again?

Comment: - Time.now is inserted in to database
- Time.now is fetched from the database, 10 minutes is added into it
- Comparison with time(from db) and current time(Time.now) is not working as it should. Wrong object types maybe?

Comment: What MySQL format is the `last_failed_attempt_time` column? If your migration declared the column as a `:time` type rather than a `:datetime` type you're gonna have issues.

Comment: A `:time` type is stored in the database as just that, a time of day (no date information attached). If you open up your dbconsole and run a direct query you should be able to see this. When Rails retrieves that value it converts it to an object of the Ruby `Time` class and gives it the date `2000-01-01` (because a Ruby `Time` includes a date). However when you use Time.now, that  has the current date attached (which I think is what you want in this case). Thus `time.to_i` is always gonna be less than `Time.now.to_i` regardless (might take a `.reload`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different types of！
you can do like this:

`user[0].last_failed_attempt_time - Time.now > 10.minutes`